# linked list not giving desired output

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

```
void create_e(struct department **,char *);
void create(struct department **s,char *str)
{     struct department *temp,*e;
     temp=(struct department *)malloc(sizeof(struct department));
     temp->dname=str;
     temp->dep=NULL;
     temp->emp=NULL;
     if(*s==NULL)
     {
         *s=temp;
         e=temp;
         create_e(&e,temp->dname);

     }
     else
     {
         e->dep=temp;
         e=temp;
         create_e(&e,temp->dname);
     }
}
void create_e(struct department **s,char *str)
{int x,i;
    printf("enter the employee details of %s \n",str);
    printf("enter the no of employee:");

    scanf("%d",&x);

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
      struct employee *temp1,*e1;
      temp1=(struct employee *)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
      char *name;
      printf("enter emp name:");
      scanf("%s",name);
       temp1->ename=name;
      int age,salary;
      printf("enter age:");
      scanf("%d",&age);
      printf("enter salary:");
      scanf("%d",&salary);

      temp1->age=age;
      temp1->salary=salary;
      temp1->next=NULL;
      if((*s)->emp==NULL)
      {
          (*s)->emp=temp1;
          e1=temp1;
      }
      else
      {
          e1->next=temp1;
          e1=temp1;
      }
    }
}
```

This is program for a linked list in a linked list.first list is the department whose structure is

```
      struct department
     {
      char *dname;
       struct department *dep;
      struct employee *emp;
     }
```

the second is employees with their names,age and salary

```
   struct employee
 {
char *ename;
int age;
int salary;
struct employee *next;
 };
```

my question was to display the linked lists.Everything displays just fine except for the employee names.The name of the last employee from the last department is displayed in-place of all the other employees name.The display function is fine I have tried it with other programs.
For example, the output should be:

```
maths->john|23|20->ron|24|25
sci->harry|19|8->chris|21|40
```

but the output comes out to be:

```
maths->chris|23|20->chris|24|25
sci->chris|19|8->chris|21|40
```

Comment: `e->dep=temp;` : `e` is uninitialized.

Comment: @Ali  At which edge of the list are you trying to insert new elements?

Comment: both horizontal and vertical

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: yes, that's right. And `e->dep=temp` is useless anyway. Removing it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is wrong, a miracle that it works. You're reading into undefined address (wrong, wrong !!), then you reuse the same wrong address for all employees.

```
  char *name;  // undefined, unallocated
  printf("enter emp name:");  // this is correct :)
  scanf("%s",name);  // scanf just stores the name here, in the woods
  temp1->ename=name;  // you copy the unitialized pointer with correct data, which gets overwritten each time
```

Had you declared: `char *name = NULL;` it would have crashed right away (would have been better, actually)

write:

```
  char name[100]; // properly allocated buffer on the stack
  printf("enter emp name:");
  scanf("%99s",name);  // truncates if more than 99: safety
  temp1->ename=strdup(name); // allocate the right amount of memory & copy string
```

EDIT: BLUEPIXY pointed some other error, he's right

in `create`:

```
else
     {
         e->dep=temp;  // e is not initialized here
         e=temp;   // now ok
         create_e(&e,temp->dname);
     }
```

just remove the `e->dep=temp` as it has no functional effect, but writes in unitialized memory.

Comment: You should use the string length specifier so `scanf` doesn't overrun the input string buffer. E.g. `char name[100]; scanf("%99s", &name);`

Comment: what if i just initialize char *name=NULL;?

Comment: and also in the function create(), I have done the same thing with temp->dname=str.Why doesn't this cause problem there?

Comment: @Ali I don't know, I don't see how `create` is called. But if str has been passed valid by the caller, it will work. ex: create(&s,"the department"). Address of constant string will be copied: valid and all right. But BLUEPIXY noted that you're also using `e` unitialized in `create`: same thing as before: it's a miracle that it works.